# Looking to show date that a cell is updated

Tags: macros, openoffice-calc

I'm looking for a way to display the date that a cell was modified, in another cell. For example:

if I make a change to A1 on the 1st of January then A2 would show `01/01/2014`.

I would also like to know how to have a cell which displays the date something was modified, but only if in a certain way. For example:

only when A1 is changed to read `yes` then A2 shows that change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static timestamp in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508263/static-timestamp-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula, put in A2:

```
=IF(A1<>"";IF(A2<>"";A2;NOW());"")
```

This will

- only do something, if `A1` is filled,
- check if `A2` is already filled... then leave it
- else insert a timestamp

For your second question - just add the condition:

```
=IF(A1="yes";IF(A2<>"";A2;NOW());"")
```

edit: This will work for **OpenOffice** (Apache, LibreOffice, .org), if you switch on "iterative references" [Tools...>Options...>Calc>Calculate]

Comment: One issue I see with this, is that it won't be a timestamp. It will always show the current date and time whenever the sheet is recalculated.

Comment: No, it won't be recalculated, that's what the second `IF` is for.
 
I'm using this formula since 3 years in a spreadsheet - can do `CTRL+Shift+F9` without messing up the old dates.

Comment: For me (win 7, xl2010 32bit) your formula does nothing... And it relies on circular references, which can be unreliable and hard to control/debug.

Comment: You are right about circular references.
Sorry I didn't state that I use OOo :)
Will add to the answer.

Comment: I missed that in the OP tags, too.